# mysql4-install-1.0.0.php file not working for Mageno 1.5

Tags: magento

Recently i have created on custom magento extension and i would like to release it but i found the installtion file does not install.

The installation file is not creating the tables.

I have following code in config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tricore_Contactus>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Tricore_Contactus>
    </modules>
.
.
.
</config>
```

I have created mysql4-install-1.0.0.php file in sql\contactus_setup folder inside extension with below code.

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
    INSERT INTO ".Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix()."core_email_template  VALUES
    (NULL, 'Tricore Contact us', 'Name: {{var data.name}}\r\nE-mail: {{var data.email}}\r\nTelephone: {{var data.mobilenumber}}\r\n\r\nComment: {{var data.message}}', NULL, 1, 'Contact Form', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2013-04-23 11:04:45', 'contacts_email_email_template', '{\"var data.name\":\"Sender Name\",\"var data.email\":\"Sender Email\",\"var data.telephone\":\"Sender Telephone\",\"var data.comment\":\"Comment\"}'),
    (NULL, 'Tricore Auto Respond', 'Dear {{var data.name}}\r\n\r\nWe have got your submitted information.\r\n\r\nE-mail: {{var data.email}}\r\nelephone: {{var data.mobilenumber}}\r\n\r\nComment: {{var data.message}}\r\n\r\nOur representative will respond you soon.\r\n', NULL, 1, 'Autoreply ', NULL, NULL, NULL, '2013-04-23 11:07:46', 'contacts_email_email_template', '{\"var data.name\":\"Sender Name\",\"var data.email\":\"Sender Email\",\"var data.telephone\":\"Sender Telephone\",\"var data.comment\":\"Comment\"}');
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

When the extension install it add entry into core_resource table but it does not insert reocrd into core_email_template table.

Sometime it does not call mysql4-install-1.0.0.php file.`enter code here`

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Everything you've posted seems right.
So maybe you forgot the following http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

In your case the xml would be:

```
 <global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <resources>
        <contactus_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Tricore_Contactus</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </contactus_setup>
        <contactus_write>
             <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </contactus_write>
        <contactus_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </contactus_read>
    </resources>
    <!-- ... -->
</global>
```

Also on a sidenote:
for debugging those I add a die("SQL-SCRIPT IS RUNNING") at the bottom of the mysql4-...php so I can be sure, that the code is at least executed - and if the sql just doesn't get applied, I can hit F5 until it works (in contrast to change the core_resources entry all the time).. and if the "die" doesn't display you can be sure, that your xml is the problem